# Understanding the public access behaviour in umbraco 7

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I have a page with public access, role based authentication, on it. Now when I surf to this page I see my login page, but the url is still the one of the protected page.

Why is this? Can we change this so it redirects normal to the login page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built in behaviour of Umbraco is to keep the protected URL in the browser and then display the login page on it. As far as I know, you can't change this behaviour out of the box, but if it bothers you, you can add a check to your login view to check of the request URL matches the URL of the login node (it shouldn't do in in your case), and do a redirect to the actual login page if they're different.

I believe this is done so that it doesn't have to redirect you once you've logged in, as you're still on the URL that you originally requested.